# Managing Azure Devops (VSTS) PATs across a team

Tags: azure-devops, azure-security

We have some external services that access VSTS using PAT authentication. Currently it seems that only individual users can create a PAT and deploy it to the service. Other users across the team do not have access to the PAT in any way, but it is necessary for:

1. Auditing PAT rights and privileges.
2. User B revoking PAT created by User A in the event User A is not available.
3. Managing PAT replacement due to expiration.

Is there a method for a group to create and manage PATs?